# SQL: Return table with nearest element and its neighbour if related to start element

Tags: sql, sql-server, oledb

I model in Sparx EA as the following image:

[image: example]

In my documentation I "start" from Stereotype 1 Element, hence #OBJECTID# is the Object_ID of Stereotype 1 Element.

What I want is a table like the following:

Stereotype 2 Element 1 | -

Stereotype 2 Element 2 | Stereotype 3 Element 1

In text;
The first column should list all related Stereotype 2, and if there is a Stereotype 3 related to both the Stereotype 2 and the "start" (Stereotype 1), Stereotype 3 should be in the second column.

Getting column one is easy;

```sql
select distinct stereo1.ea_guid AS CLASSGUID, stereo1.Object_Type AS CLASSTYPE, stereo1.Name AS stereo1Name
from ((t_object stereo1
inner join t_connector start2stereo1Connector on start2stereo1Connector.End_Object_ID = stereo1.Object_ID AND stereo1.Stereotype = 'Stereotype 1')
inner join t_object start on start2stereo1Connector.Start_Object_ID = #OBJECTID#)
```

But how do I add the second column? I have tried a lot of stuff but not quite got there.

I would prefer an SQL-solution if possible and avoiding scripting.

This is what I managed so far:

```sql
select stereo2.ea_guid AS CLASSGUID, stereo2.Object_Type AS CLASSTYPE, stereo2.Name, stereo3.Name, stereo3.Note as stereo3Note
from ((((t_object stereo2
    INNER JOIN t_connector stereo1Con on stereo1Con.Start_Object_ID = #OBJECTID)
    INNER JOIN t_connector stereo3ConOut on stereo3ConOut.End_Object_ID = stereo1Con.End_Object_ID)
    INNER JOIN t_object stereo3 on stereo3.Object_ID = stereo3ConOut.Start_Object_ID)
    INNER JOIN t_connector stereo3ConIn on stereo3ConIn.Start_Object_ID = #OBJECTID# AND stereo3ConIn.End_Object_ID = stereo3.Object_ID)
WHERE stereo2.Object_ID = stereo1Con.End_Object_ID AND stereo2.Stereotype = 'Stereotype 2'
```

This gives me the table I want with one exception:
elements with Stereotype 2, without relation to a Stereotype 3, is missing from the table. I tried LEFT JOIN with no success.

How do I include ALL Stereotype 2 elements, even if they do not have a relation to any Stereotype 3?

Comment: Please show your table structure, sample data instead of only that relationship image.

Comment: Well, table structure is from Sparx EA, see chapter 1.3 here: (https://leanpub.com/InsideEA/read)

Sample data.. We are supposed to build the data.

We start at a requirement which is allocated to modules or components. Each requirement will have a related interpretation and requirement response.

What I want is to get a table with all requirements for a specific module/component and the intepretation/requirement response.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I'm sorry. It is a OLEDB MS SQL Server v7.0 as far as I can tell.